# Use google font in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add a Google font to the Wordpress Cyberchimps responsive theme.

https://cyberchimps.com/forum-topic/where-do-i-override-the-default-font/

I've tried to embed the link to the font in the header, but it doesn't update to use it.

How can I use the custom font?

Answer (score 1):

To use google fonts in your website, you simply need to put a link in the head of your page ( in a similar manner like you add css files ). Like this :-

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+DW+Pica' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And access it in you css like this :-

```
.im-fell-dw-pica-font{
    font-family: 'IM Fell DW Pica', sans-serif; 
}
```

Here `'IM Fell DW Pica'` is the google font required.( Note that sans-serif is defined after our required font 'IM Fell DW Pica'. This is done so that the browser loads sans-serif font if our google font is not loaded for some reason. )

You can now apply this class to the element you want like this :-

```
<div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font">Some random text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - is there a manner in Wordpress to apply the font globally?

Comment: @MaxRussell ya you can do it in pretty much the same manner. Please refer the [following link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-add-google-web-fonts-wordpress-themes/)

Comment: Also, I'm specifically looking for how to do this with the Wordpress interface and see it. Sometimes seems a bit 'closed'

Comment: @MaxRussell the link i gave you does the job you need buddy ! What do you mean by `closed` ?